# CMS url not opening in browser via implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, activitynotfoundexception, android-implicit-intent

I am trying to open news feed which has url extension .cms

Instead when tried simple url e.g. http://www.google.com/, it works as expected but not for .cms page.

I don't want to add my own WebView. I am pretty sure that .cms is causing the problem but don't know how to resolve it with ready-made/third-party browser.

```
public static void openLinkInExternalBrowser(Context context, String url) {
  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
   context.startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

When I try to open it, I get below exception

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/spurned-lovers-tip-off-helped-track-kill-top-jaish-terrorist-khalid/articleshow/61013573.cms  }
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1936)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4471)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:54)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4429)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:708)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4788)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4756)
                                                                 at adapters.NewsAdapter$1.onClick(NewsAdapter.java:66)
                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6219)
                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24482)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: the link works perfectly using intent for me..which os version you tried?

Comment: Android Oreo 8.0 and Marshmallow 6.0

Comment: I tired in the oreo 8.0 and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you find any problem in my code then?

Comment: No even your code is fine.I tried this link http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/spurned-lovers-tip-off-helped-track-kill-top-jaish-terrorist-khalid/articleshow/61013573.cms

Comment: Strange behaviour!!! Still crashing at my end

Comment: I hope you are having a browser in your device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156311/discussion-between-vvb-and-anonymous).

Comment: i fixed your problem just wait for the post

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons your url might have been using "www".So try to wrap it with either "http" or "https".This works for me now.

```
public static void openLinkInExternalBrowser(Context context, String url) {
    if (!url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("http://")){ 
        url = "http://" + url; 
    }
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
   context.startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Comment: No. On doing so I get message "Site can't be reached" indeed it is opening fine on browser by copy pasting same url. if condition is causing url damage

Comment: What I am guessing is this is isn't code problem..I guess there is some problem with your dns or something like that.Try adding hardcoded url as url and check.

Comment: No but same url is copied in mobile browser and works